# Discord bot running commands twice discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here is the main bot and a cog all the commands in all of the cogs are running twice whenever called and I know there is only 1 instance of the bot running and there are no duplicate commands. I have even switched text editors and have had multiple people look over my code and they can't figure it out any help is needed thanks.

Main Bot called main_Bot.py

```py
#imports
from cogs.database import database
import discord
import time
import random
from discord.abc import GuildChannel
from discord.embeds import Embed
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os
import json
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from discord.ext import tasks
os.chdir(os.getcwd())




intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="-",intents=intents)
client.remove_command("help")
client.load_extension("cogs.moderation")
client.load_extension("cogs.fun")
client.load_extension("cogs.events")
client.load_extension("cogs.eco")
client.load_extension("cogs.help")
print("loaded")




async def newServer(ctx,guild):

    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles,name = "Muted")
   
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    #when the bot powers on
    print("Ready")
    print(discord.__version__)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game('Type -help'))
    clearTXT.start()
    DailyTimer.start()
    muteTime.start()




@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def clearTXT():
    with open("spam_detect.txt", "r+") as file:
        file.truncate(0)
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def DailyTimer():
    users = await database.get_bank_data()
        
    for i in users:
            
        user = await client.fetch_user(i)
        daily_timer = users[str(user.id)]["daily_timer"]
        if daily_timer <= 0:
            users[str(user.id)]["daily"] = True
        else:
            users[str(user.id)]["daily_timer"] -= 10
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def muteTime():
    users = await database.get_muted_data()
    mod_chat = client.get_channel(778671755115888670)
    print("muted Time")
    for i in users:
            print("Looped")
            user = await client.fetch_user(i)
            print(user)
            daily_timer = users[str(user.id)]["time"]
            print(daily_timer)
            if daily_timer > 0:
                users[str(i)]["time"] -= 60
                print("Munis 60")
                with open("muted_players.json", "w") as f:
                    json.dump(users,f,indent=2)  
                
                

            else:
            

                print("unmuted")
                getGuild = users[str(user.id)]["server"]
                guild = client.get_guild(getGuild)
                member = guild.get_member(user.id)
                mute_role=discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")
                await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
            #  await deleteMuted(user)  
                with open("muted_players.json", "w") as f:
                    users.pop(str(user.id))
                    json.dump(users,f,indent=2) 
                embed = discord.Embed(description= f"✅ **{member.display_name} mute has run out and is now unmuted**", color=discord.Color.green())
                await mod_chat.send(embed=embed)


#run client server
client.run('' )
```

One of the Cogs called fun.py

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

class fun(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):

        self.client = client
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Fun Cog Loaded")
    
    @commands.command(name="test")
    async def test(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send("this is a test")



    @commands.command(name="embed")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def embed(self,ctx,channel:discord.TextChannel,title, * ,words_embed):
        person = ctx.author.display_name
        words = words_embed
        print(words)
        em = discord.Embed(title = title, color = discord.Color.dark_red())
        em.description = words
    #  em.add_field(name=person,value=words)
    # em.set_footer(text = person)
        await channel.send(embed = em)
        await ctx.message.delete()



    @commands.command(name="message")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def embed(self,ctx,channel:discord.TextChannel, * words_embed):

        words = ' '.join([str(words) for words in words_embed]) 
        print(words)
        await channel.send(words)
        await ctx.message.delete()

    @commands.command(name='wiki')
    async def wikipedia(self,ctx):
        a = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"
        u = requests.get(a)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(u.content, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.find(class_ = "firstHeading").text
        title = title.replace(" ", "_")
        url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s' %title
        await ctx.send(f"""Here is your random Wikipedia article! 
    {title} - {url}""")


    @commands.command(name="flip")
    async def flip(self,ctx):
        results = random.randrange(0,2)
        print(results)
        if results == 1:
            em = discord.Embed(title = f"The coin landed on Heads!", color = discord.Color.dark_blue())
            await ctx.send(embed = em)
        elif results == 0:
            em = discord.Embed(title = f"The coin landed on Tails!", color = discord.Color.dark_blue())
            await ctx.send(embed = em)

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(fun(client))
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't running any hidden python processes? To check open the task manager (`Ctrl + Shift + Esc`)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I checked task manager before it only is running once no hidden.

Comment: Are you running the python file using an IDE? Like vscode or pycharm?

Comment: yes im using VS Code.

Comment: Try closing it, and all instances in the task manager, if it doesn't work try also restarting your pc

Comment: Is every command being executed twice? Or only certain commands?

Comment: All commands are being run twice and I have also tried restarting my computer and VS Code

Comment: Have you always had the `os.chdir(os.getcwd)` at the top?

Comment: Yes I have always had it even before I added the Cogs.

Comment: I haven't used that method before, so I'm a newbie on that portion, but try removing that, because that seems to do something with directories/files.

Comment: still goes twice

Comment: Hmm... that's wierd.

Comment: Maybe try adding `return` at the end of a few commands. Then test those commands out.

Comment: I already have debug commands I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Normally, when the code reaches a `return` statement, it will exit the function. If that doesn't work, and it is still executing twice, then there's something outside of the code that is making the code run twice.

Comment: Where are you running the code on?

Answer (score 2):

[This reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/jmf04m/2_instances_of_1_bot/) provides the solution:

If there is a

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(..):
```

function in any of the other cogs extensions you load,
remove the line

```
await self.client.process_commands(message)
```

from its body. It is not needed inside an extension file loaded by cogs, only in a main file.